# Pyspark dynamic column name

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe which contains months and will change quite frequently. I am saving this dataframe values as list e.g. months = ['202111', '202112', '202201']. Using a for loop to to iterate through all list elements and trying to provide dynamic column values with following code:

```py
for i in months:
    df = (
        adjustment_1_prepared_df.select("product", "mnth", "col1", "col2")
        .groupBy("product")
        .agg(
            f.min(f.when(condition, f.col("col1")).otherwise(9999999)).alias(
                concat("col3_"), f.lit(i.col)
            )
        )
    )
```

So basically in alias I am trying to give column name as a combination of constant (minInv_) and a variable (e.g. 202111) but I am getting error. How can I give a column name as combination of fixed string and a variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error? I would construct the column name in the for loop before you call the df to add the new column

Comment: if `months = ['202111', '202112', '202201']`, what is `i.col for i in months` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.alias("col3_"+str(i.col))`